# Binding Fields in List With $ObjectType global variable

Tags: apex, global-variables

Is it possible to bind Binding Fields in List With $ObjectType global variable.
I have a few fields of Contact object to be checked if createable. 
Is it possible if i store all the field names in a list and try accessing then using loop like `*Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.**fieldnamegoeshere**.isCreateable()*`

Comment: You can do that in a wrapper class, please specify what do you intend to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do it in the following way:

```
Set<SObjectField> contactSobjFields = new Set<SObjectField> {
    Contact.Name
};
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> conactFieldsMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
for(SObjectField sobfField :contactSobjFields){
    Schema.SObjectField field = conactFieldsMap.get(sobfField.getDescribe().getName());
    System.debug(field.getDescribe().isCreateable());
}
```